# datastudio.google.com refused to connect

Tags: html, reactjs, looker-studio

I am trying to embed a Google Data Studio report to my website. It was working until a minute ago, but now I keep getting: "datastudio.google.com refused to connect."

This is the code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext } from 'react'
import { Context } from '../../../context/Context'

export function ScheduleAndReport() {
  const { userObject } = useContext(Context)
  const reportURL = userObject.reportURL
  const scheduleURL = userObject.scheduleURL

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {scheduleURL && (
        <iframe
          width="100%"
          height="1200"
          src={scheduleURL}
          frameBorder="0"
          allowFullScreen>
        </iframe>
      )}
      {reportURL && (
        <iframe
          width="100%"
          height="1200"
          src={reportURL}
          frameBorder="0"
          allowFullScreen>
        </iframe>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't embed datastudio in an IFRAME .. had the same issue on FF

*To protect your security, datastudio.google.com will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it. To see this page, you need to open it in a new window.*

Here is how to do it the correct way:

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7450249?hl=en